# How to GET data based up on a variable in MEAN stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean-stack

I'm trying to retrieve all the data where It matches with the specific userId. For example, I have the below data in MongoDB database

```
{
    "_id": "hjdhs88889dsijd8",
    "items": "xxxxxx",
    "userId": "A123"
},
{
    "_id": "hjhuf77889dsijd8",
    "items": "xxxxxx",
    "userId": "A123"
}
```

I want to `GET` only the data where `userId=A123`. Below is from my back-end JS file

```
router.get('/customerList/:userId', (req,res) => {
    console.log('Retrieving list');
    cList.find({userId: req.body.userId}, (err, list) => {
      if(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      else if(list) {
        return res.json(list)
      }
    });
  });
```

When I trying to `get` the data from the postman from the below url

```
http://localhost:3000/api/customerList/A123
```

I'm getting an empty array. How do I solve this?

Comment: Did you checked your req.body.userId ??

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `req.params`

From the [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req):

```
app.get('/user/:id', function(req, res) {
  res.send('user ' + req.params.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To access [named route “parameters”](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters) use `req.params` not `req.body`

```
app.get('/myPath/:myParam', (req,res) => res.send(req.params.myParam))
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use req.params.userId instead of re.body.userId